# Linux Default Interface to bind for services

Tags: linux, centos, linux-networking, centos7

I have tomcat services running on 2 servers. Centos 7 and Centos 5.

Both servers have Public IP and Private IP.

Tomcat server.xml has adddress="auto". I could set the IP, but I'm trying to figure out why it chose a different interface.

On CentOS 5, when I start tomcat, it binds to private IP. But CentOS 7 binds to public IP. I've verified network config and it all look similar.

Public Interface is the default gateway for both servers.

I'm out of ideas to figure this out.

Public interface is has the gateway and private interface doesn't have gateway.

Centos 5 routing table:

```
   Kernel IP routing table
   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
   100.100.100.224 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
   10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
   169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
   0.0.0.0         100.100.100.225 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Centos 7 routing table

```
   Kernel IP routing table
   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
   0.0.0.0         200.200.200.225 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens192
   20.20.20.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens224
   200.200.200.224 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 ens192
   169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 ens192
   169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 ens224
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/hosts` file needed an entry for the `hostname` and its private IP.

Tomcat tries to get the default returned by `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress().`

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/cluster-receiver.html